# Metropolis Hastings when acceptance rate is not a probability

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, logarithm, metropolis-hastings

I need to implement a Metropolis Hastings where the acceptance probability  $\alpha$ is not a probability but a logarithm of a score. The logarithm of a score is a negative float.

In original algorithm i have:

```
alpha = compute acceptance probability with proposal distribution
Compute r = min(1,alpha)
Sample u in U(0,1)
Set new sample to
    x' if u < r
    x if u >= r
```

min() between 1 and alpha works fine with probability but if alpha is like -30 -(-54) or -23 - (-10), in the first case it's ok (i accept the new state), but in second case ?

Observation: I use the logarithm of a score then my acceptance probability is $$\frac{\text{score(new_state)}}{\text{score(old_state)}}$$ and with logarithm is $$\ln\text{(score(new_state))} - \ln\text{(score(old_state))}$$

Comment: We need more details. First, $\alpha$ here need not be a probability (the acceptance ratio is a better term since the numerator can be larger than the denominator). Next, is the score a posterior density? If not, what is it? How do you propose a new state?

Comment: I have temporal dataset, I need to split it in epochs (of various lenght) and then I need learn one distinct model for every epochs. The score is the likelihood of the sequence of model in respect of the dataset partitioned in epochs. If I split good I get a good score, if I split bad I get a bad score. It's a possibility to use $\exp(\ln(score($new_state$))−\ln(score($old_state$)))$ ? there is more good possibility?

Comment: Yes, you can use what you've written or you could draw $u\sim U(0,1)$ and use $\log(u)$. By default, I do the latter when I have a need for acceptance ratios in my MCMC algorithms.